Arrayformula when using index match
I have the following index match formula in this sheet.
Project Tracking Tab, column T
=IFERROR(INDEX('Staff Effort'!A8:AW,
    MATCH(A2, 'Staff Effort'!A8:A, 0),
    MATCH('Staff Effort'!AW8, 'Staff Effort'!A8:AW8, 0)),"")

What it does, is it looks at my Staff Effort Tab and pulls information into the Project tracking tab about that project using the Project ID number.

Instead of me having to copy down the formula every time I enter a new Project ID number, I would like these formulas to copy down automatically. Will array formula work for this?
**Note: Someone provided and answer to similar question that suggested VLookup something like this in the header column.
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 'Project List'!A2:B, 2, 0)))

I would like to not use vlookup, because this sheet is evolving and I will be adding columns and making changes.  Index Match allows me to make changes without having to adjust the formula.**

"would like to not use vlookup, because this sheet is evolving and I will be adding columns and making changes. Index Match allows me to make changes without having to adjust the formula" You are mistaken.  You are returning the column # in your current formula using MATCH('Staff Effort'!AW8,'Staff Effort'!A8:AW8,0) instead of hardcoding 49. You can use the same approach in that formula or VLOOKUP using simply COLUMN('Staff Effort'!AW8) I've updated the other answer

Thanks.  I would have asked this in the other answer, but did not think I was allowed to comment per other things I have seen.  This helps me fully understand the answers.

Here is the VLOOKUP formula adapted for the new sheet and column, with your concern about a hardcoded column index resolved.
Formula
=INDEX(IFNA(
   VLOOKUP(A2:A, 'Staff Effort'!A8:AW, COLUMN('Staff Effort'!AW8), 0)))

or
=LET(c,'Staff Effort'!AW8:AW, n,COLUMN(c),
  INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, OFFSET(c,,1-n),n,0))))


Note
Both of the formulas approaches above to return the column index 49 are equivalent and both adjust in the same way to the addition/removal of columns in 'Staff Effort' as your MATCH version:
=COLUMN('Staff Effort'!AW8)

=MATCH('Staff Effort'!AW8, 'Staff Effort'!A8:AW8, 0)


Thank you . Your note was extremely helpful.
